# Show different login formsand use different login auth Laravel Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Is it possible to modify the Laravel App Authentication? like I want to show different forms per different login route, like If I have 2 different login routes for admin and user.

Admin login route, can access the admin dashboard

> /app/system/login

User login route, can access only the user page

> /app/system/user/login

I tried to do

```
php artisan route:list
```

and I see this

```
LoginController@login
LoginController@showLoginForm
```

but I don't know where to find them to modify those for my requirements. Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Auth Controller is in Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php, functions get import from file Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php.

Read to documentation how create [other auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication).